# Try & catch pdo close database connection

Tags: php, pdo

```
try{
    //PDO CONNECT DB, $db

}catch(PDOException $e){die("ERROR"));}
```

I have a query user PDO connect to database.

I use try & catch, my question is if my query is error

Do i need to close conncetion before `die();`?

```
}catch(PDOException $e){$db="NULL"; die("ERROR"));}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not necessary in php. When your php process finished, the connection will be closed too.

Answer (score 6):

As a matter of fact, **you shouldn't `die()` at all**

Until you learn how to use try and catch properly, you shouldn't use this statement. It is not intended for echoing "ERROR". It has totally different purpose.

If you want to echo silly "ERROR" in case of an erroneous query, you have to do it properly.
Namely,

- send appropriape HTTP header
- **log the error** to notify a developer of the problem
- show whatever error message to the client
- **have all this stuff done in one place, not repeated for every query**

to do this, you have to set up an exception handler:

```
set_exception_handler('myExceptionHandler');
function myExceptionHandler($e)
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error', TRUE, 500);
    error_log($e->getMessage().". Trace: ".$e->getTraceAsString());
    echo "ERROR";
    exit;
}
```

put this code in your bootstrap/config file and quit wrapping **every** query into try-catch.