# Is It Possible to put one Try Catch block for all functions inside a Class in PHP

Tags: php, exception

How Can I put one Try catch block for one complete class.

PS: I know that I can separate put try catch in each function but just asking if there is a way to put on try catch above a class.

Comment: I don't think so. Usually you do encapsulate your class initialization and method calls.

Comment: You need to study again what Objec Oriented Programming is about. This question is quite nonsense.

Comment: Why not just write the functions within the class to handle possible errors that they come across? I know it takes more time, but isn't code that doesn't fail, no matter what, the goal of all good developers?

Comment: Do not ask **partial question** out of nowhere. Ask about **particular problem** you are trying to solve with this try catch

Comment: @YourCommonSense in my model class there are some 400+ functions, something is failing on user side, and I don't have any idea. So just thinking if there is way to get the error by putting one try-catch block.

Comment: Well that's sound sensible. but *why do you want try catch for this*?

Comment: **It seems most of SO folks cannot tell a negative answer from negative vote**

Comment: @YourCommonSense   From errolog I got to know its pdo exception.. so was just thinking to create a temp try catch to avoid other problems until the real problem is not being solved.

Comment: For this temporary debugging you can use try..catch in the application code, where these model function being called.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Now this is **out of sense** :)...
I just said I have no idea what is failing till now...
as 400+ function are called at 10000+ locations.... 
and you asked me to put try catch for all :)... wow.......

Comment: Well, I still can't get your problem then. Don't you have a **stack trace** in your log file? Can't it lead you to the very "real problem" you are talking about? May be you could ask (if it let you) another question, explaining your current problem with all these exceptions? I don't quite understand it.

Comment: @YourCommonSense yes **Stack trace** is there but I didn't get the situation where exactly the error is being thrown..
I asked this question for just sake of instant temporary solution.. 
Anyway Thanks for help... let me start debugging the code, rather then enjoying **SO**...

Comment: Don't blame this site too much. There are too many people here and you never can actually tell if you get an answer or have your question closed or downvoted. Most of time you get an answer though. Just a bad luck. Debugging would be the best choice anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your clarification from the comment, it seems you don't need no try or catch. But [**exception handler**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18606356/285587) instead.

Just have your 400+ methods have to throw 400+ exceptions - they all will be processed in one handler.

P.S. It seems most of SO folks cannot tell a negative answer from negative vote

Comment: thanks :).. it looks nice for temporary solution...

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't do that. The reason to use try catch is to catch specific exceptions wich may be different for each function in a class.

Wrong:

```
class Test
{
    try {
        public function foo(){
            return 'foo';
        }

        public function bar(){
            return 'bar';
        }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Correct:

```
class Test
{
    function foo(){
        try {
            return 'foo';
        catch (\Excepetion $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    function bar(){
        try {
            return 'bar';
        catch (\Excepetion $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: errr. return error message?!

Comment: This is just an example, it should be adapted to solve the problem. As there were no problem specified i just made this up to simulate a situation.

Comment: @EdsonHorácioJunior Thanks for your hard core efforts... :P